# Screen Flickering in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: screen

**SETUP**

- Processor - Intel® Core™ i3-3220 CPU @ 3.30GHz × 4
- Graphics - Intel® Ivybridge Desktop

**Problem**

I updated to Ubuntu 18.04, and I'm facing tremendous screen flickering/shaking/distorting at random times for random duration.
The display is working fine on another Monitor that I have.

Answer (score 10):

I was observing screen flickering but not shaking. I had to edit my monitor config and change the framerate. By default mine was set to 60.169086456298828.

open terminal and run the following:

```
gedit ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

edit this line:

```
<rate>60.1690864562988</rate>
```

set it to be lower than 60 as mentioned by 4levels, I used 59.96.

Comment: You do not need to use `sudo` when edit a file within your home directory `~`...

Comment: Actually this helped to get rid of the flickering screen on my T570 with switchable graphics in Intel mode. The refresh rate is accessible as a drop-down option via system settings -> devices -> displays -> refresh rate. Thank you for pointing out the refresh rate as a possible solution!

Comment: I had to disconnect the monitor and connect it again after editing the file to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I just deactivate the compositor from settings/GUI.
I'm new to Linux and stuff but this work for me,
I'm using Kubuntu on a very old system/pc.

[image: as seen in the picture]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I updated my Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 LTS. The 18.04 is running by default on linux kernel v4.15 while new kernel version v5.0 and above are available. Try to change the kernel version using:
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Download packages according to your requirements, i.e., generic/low latency and install.

This solved my problem.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and disabling my compositor worked too. `compton` was glitching text on my screen. Disabled it and all is well.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, my answer is in a similar vein to the highest voted answer here, except I name the troublemaking compositor. I've reworded it to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Ubuntu 20.04 and Virtualbox 6.1.

I reinstalled it, this time by selecting the correct type of OS in Virtualbox in the first step. It works well now.