# Screen tearing in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Intel graphics

Tags: drivers, 20.04, intel-graphics, tearing

I am facing unpleasant screen tearing when watching videos since some time, I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on a Lenovo IdeaPad C340 laptop and I do not understand why it appeared (after some update I guess).

Here is the output of `lspci -nn | egrep -i "3d|displa|vga"`:

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) [8086:3ea0] (rev 02)`

I have tried already several things that I found on the internet, but unfortunately none of them did work for me, I have created a file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with following content :

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics"
    Driver "Intel"
    Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
    Option "DRI" "3"
    Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

And also a file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel-graphics.conf` with following content:

```
Section "Module"
    Load "dri3"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "DRI"   "3"
EndSection
```

Following methods suggested respectively [Screen Tearing on Ubuntu Xorg 20.04 with Intel Graphics](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-screen-tearing-on-ubuntu-xorg-20-04-with-intel-graphics/) and [YouTube: How to Fix Intel Graphics Horizontal Lines Tearing Bug in Debian, Linux Mint and Ubuntu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=4&v=IJeX35wbZY4&feature=emb_logo).

Any help would be appreciated!

```
System:    Host: sim0mo-c340 Kernel: 5.4.0-48-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Convertible System: LENOVO product: 81N5 v: Lenovo IdeaPad C340-15IWL serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0J40700 WIN serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: LENOVO v: ALCN24WW(V2.01) 
           date: 03/29/2019 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 44.1 Wh condition: 49.0/52.5 Wh (93%) 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-8265U bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
           Speed: 900 MHz min/max: 400/3900 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 887 2: 899 3: 885 4: 898 5: 900 6: 901 7: 900 8: 900 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0 256 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 20.0.8 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-48-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] driver: iwlwifi 
           IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: 3c:f0:11:fd:c2:30 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 238.47 GiB used: 92.79 GiB (38.9%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVLB256HAHQ-000L2 size: 238.47 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 171.53 GiB used: 92.75 GiB (54.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 40.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 315 Uptime: 18m Memory: 7.50 GiB used: 2.75 GiB (36.6%) Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: Hi SimOmo, did you try to log with Wayland display server: https://askubuntu.com/a/1250859/1094194 ?

Comment: yes it works perfectly with Wayland ! Thank you for your suggestion.