# Screen flashin in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, flicker

I installed Ubuntu for the first time yesterday. Followed a guide and the OS installer. I have a dual-boot with Windows 10. My computer is an Acer Aspire A315-21G.

Specs:

Processor: AMD A9-9420 3 GHz Dual-core (2 Core™)

Graphics: AMD Radeon™ R5 Graphics DDR4 SDRAM

I get these random flashes of black in the screen while using Ubuntu. Nothing during start-up, only on the desktop environment.

I have tried the solutions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062031/screen-flickering-in-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts) and in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231441/ubuntu-screen-flickering?noredirect=1&lq=1). Nothing worked.

I thought it might be a driver issue so I tried updating my drivers, but they were already updated. One of the posts mentioned high frame rate and to edit monitors.xml but the file is not there (the post was for Ubuntu 18.04).

I would believe it has something to do with this, but don't know how to change it.

EDIT: just tried watching a video and the quality sucked. I guess that means that the problem is in the driver/graphics(?). But don't know how to fix it since ubuntu says my drivers are up-to-date.

Comment: Acer A315-41G-R4BW, same problem.